# Does editing an EER diagram update a schema?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've just reengineered a model and EER diagram on a schema with no relationships using Workbench. On the EER diagram I created a foreign key relationship between two tables. I saved and exited and then went and had a look at my schema in the normal editor view and the foreign key wasn't reflected there. Should it have been?

Comment: to be honest i don't know what exactly you mean workbench maybe?

Comment: Yep - will update post

Comment: Remember, in a Structured Query Language, it's the Query that ultimately determines the Structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have after you made your changes in the EER

synchronize the model it

[image: Workbench synchronze model]

And then follow the steps.
Of course amke a backup before changing anything, and you can of course change it afterwards back.